# LESS importing CSS and relative paths

Tags: css, less

I am using LESS to organize and import all my CSS files. I am also using Twitter Bootstrap which I integrated inside my style.less. It works fine like below however when I use lessc to minify the less file and compress it to one all hell breaks loose with my twitter bootstrap css. The reason is that my `bootstrap.min.css` has a relative path to images as `"../img"` so when I minify all these files and dump my output file, it no longer finds this path.

How exactly should I fix this, I don't want to be hardcoding absolute urls in my css?

```
style.less
    @import './folder_one/file_one';
    @import './folder_one/file_two';
    @import './folder_two/file_one';
    @import './folder_three/file_one';
    // this bootstrap css references images relatively ../img/
    @import './bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: I recommand you to use `.htaccess` for that.

Answer (score 16):

When running lessc use the [--relative-urls](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-relative-urls) flag.

```
lessc --relative-urls
```

It's poorly documented, but by default it is false which means that all @imported files will maintain their urls (e.g. background-image, font-face, etc) as they are. This is because less was already doing this and many users expect it to leave their urls alone.

When the relative-urls flag is used, lessc rewrites all of the urls according to the location of the less/css file being imported.

**Example**

*/dir1/style/main.less*

```
// if you don't include (less) lessc will leave bootstrap
//   as an @import at the top of the lessified css file
@import (less) '../bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css';
```

*/dir1/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css*

```
background-image:url("../img/bs-img.gif");
```

Result:

*/dir1/style/main.css*

```
background-image:url("../bootstrap/img/bs-img.gif");
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the docs for command line usage.
https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/wiki/Command-Line-Usage. There's an option called `--root-path` that will prepend existing urls so that they will work in the output css file.

```
lessc [option option=parameter ...] <source> [destination]

lessc -rp=will/be/prepended sourcefile.less path/to/destination
```

---

For example:

Here is the original url, with the file in css/src/nest

```
background-image: url('../../../imgs/bg.png');
```

And this is what I would do on the command line. Note that the `-rp` argument should point **from the output directory to the original file location**

```
lessc -rp=src/nest css/src/nest/nesty.less css/nesty.less
```

And the output, with the file in css/

```
  background-image:url('src/nest/../../../imgs/bg.png')
```

---

There is a `--relative-urls` option, but I can't get it to work. I'm working build script that uses the workaround I described above. [Build-o-Matic](https://github.com/positlabs/Build-o-Matic)

This is how I handled determining the path [[link]](https://github.com/positlabs/Build-o-Matic/blob/master/modules/compile_styles.py#L50)

Comment: Try using relative paths, add flag -ru or --relative-urls, it worked in my case (using lessc 1.4.0).

Comment: Right. I mentioned that. The whole reason for this workaround is that the -ru option wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

i just had this problem and solved it.
the solution is to prepend `../` to the path of the style sheet that you want to import until it finds it. look here :

[image]

then i added `../` multiple times until i escaped to the wanted directory and it worked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`--relative-urls` flag has its in-browser counterpart.

```
<script>
less = {
    env: "development",
    relativeUrls: true
};
</script>
<script src="less.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got here because i also had the problem with resolving image uri's in my less file.

"--relative-urls" has pointed me in the right direction.

For anyone else who also gets here:
This argument is deprecated, you can use now "--rewrite-urls" with "off", "all" or "local" - [detailed description here](https://lesscss.org/usage/#less-options-rewrite-urls)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).