# LESS compiler and relative @import references not working in Web Essentials 2012 v2.7

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, import, less, web-essentials

The update to v2.6 works from with VS 2012 and I have the Web Tools 2012.2 update installed, but a problem that I noticed that does not exist in the v2.5.1 version (I downgraded to fix for now) is that the @import lines in LESS files do not locate the referenced files anymore when compiling.

The compiler bombs unless the file referenced in the @import line is in the same physical folder. If any path information exists, such as "../../style/common.less", the compiler responds with an error and won't create the generated CSS file.

The error that I get is that it cannot find the file and the path information is truncated to either the first parent path construct or none. So, it's looking for "../style/common.less" or "style/common.less". It seems to be intermittent between the two.

For a possibly related issue, see: [LESS importing CSS and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813400/less-importing-css-and-relative-paths)

**UPDATE:**
Confirmed that the expected behavior works correctly in LESS v1.3.1 and below.

I updated to v2.6 of Web Essentials via the Visual Studio extensions update dialog. Then I replaced the contents of the LESS script file in the path *X:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions\{HASH}\Resources\Scripts\less-1.3.0.js* (which was v1.3.3 originally with the Web Essentials v2.6 update) with the scripts for versions 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.4.0-beta, 1.4.0 and 1.4.1. The compiles only worked with versions 1.3.1 and lower.

I'm wondering if something got broken when support for @import-once was removed.

**UPDATE 2:**
Version 2.7 of Web Essentials still exhibits this behavior, but can be fixed also as per above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2.6 has the 1.3.3 version of the official LESS compiler. It might have a bug. I'll investigate this issue and release an update when I have a fix.

Thanks for reporting this!

**UPDATE: FIXED!**

This has now been verified and fixed for VS 2012 as of July 16, 2013.

Version 2.8 of Web Essentials addresses the issue in this question, so if you update again from within Visual Studio 2012 or by manually installing the extension you will be able to use the LESS compiler for relative @import statements.

It will only work with LESS 1.3.3 (the version packaged with the extension), but this shouldn't be an issue since it now works out-of-the-box.

To see what else was updated in v2.8 of the extension, check the change log:
http://vswebessentials.com/changelog

Thanks to Mads Kristensen and the rest of the team that helped to fix this!

**UPDATE: VS AUTO-UPDATE**

v2.8.1 of the extension for VS 2013 pushed out to the Visual Studio Extension Gallery. You should get the VS auto-update message or go to "Tools > Extensions and Updates..." menu item and update from there.

Comment: Hi, any news on this.  I came across the same problem yesterday :(

Comment: Same problem here, used the OP fix but it would be nice to release an update.

Comment: Same problem. I have version less.js 1.3.0 and it works but only for relative path like '../'. If I add 2 folders back, '../../', it doesnt' work

Comment: @Draykos, the file still must be named "less-1.3.0.js", but the contents are v1.3.3 out-of-the-box from the VS update. Only version 1.3.1 and below work correctly. Make sure the contents of the file contains the correct version of the code.

Comment: Import in 2.8 is massively broken for me now. I'll post a bug report.

Comment: Regarding the comment above: if b.less imports a.less and c.less imports b.less, the output of c.less is empty.

Comment: I'm seeing a problem similar to @AndreLoker.  If multiple LESS files are importing the same file, the result of compilation can be empty. This broke as soon as I updated to to 2.8.

Comment: I managed to fix the most serious problems by following the suggestions by rjgotten: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/pull/25#issuecomment-21098875 (requires manual modification of the plugin files)

Comment: @EricBrenden: That should be fixed by https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/pull/30

Comment: @AndreLoker: You can backport the fix yourself by copying the new files over to the resources directory in the installed extension.  (all that changes was the external JS & WSF files)

Comment: import-once is also broken in 2.8 if your imported files ALSO contain similar import-ince references (which unfortunately, was the point)

Comment: in VS2012 the current WebEssentials 3.0 still gives me wrong paths when my root "A.less" includes a "B/B.less" containing a relative url (like img1/1.png).. What I get in A.css (=the file I include in the page) is "url(img1/1.png)", which is the same I would get compiling B.less alone, while I was expecting "url(B/img1/1.png)". The latter works, the former does not. My current workaround is to replace the provided less-1.4.2.min.js with the older less-1.3.3.min.js and this at the moment works well..

Answer (score 3):

This is now [fixed](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/pull/25) and [released](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog) for VS 2013.

Comment: Any suggestions for developers using VS 2012?

Comment: So, was this a problem with Web Essentials, the LESS compiler, or something else? Has development on the Web Essentials/Web Tools for 2012 stopped?

Comment: @NeilMonroe: It was a problem with the wrapper that let the LESS compiler work through WSH.  https://github.com/SLaks/WebEssentials2013/commit/f3c40f04445b73cf50f6ce0827b816411181d019

Comment: @JacobT.Nielsen: I asked Mads.  https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/pull/25#issuecomment-21067466

Comment: @JacobT.Nielsen: This has been released for VS2012.  http://vswebessentials.com/changelog